# 2013 Workflow server state C#

Tags: workflow, workflow-manager

I use 2013 workflows in my SharePoint solution.

A few days ago the workflow server shut down and the SharePoint app did not work properly. So I wonder if there is a possibility to check the state of the Workflow server before the user gets to use the app?

So I could check if the server is reachable and display an error otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the workflow service? You can navigate to yourdomain:12291/ and auth as a user belonging to the workflow manager admin group - see if you get back an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was my exact thought. But what if the server is running, but has an error.
Then I would get a 500 error back, but not what the problem really is. So I cannot log the error to the ULS for example.

best regards
Alex

Comment: Please comment under an answer if you want to reply to it. :-) Well yes, if your Workflow Manager Service is in a bad state you will receive back an error instead of a normal XML file - wasn't that the quesion? How to check if the Workflow Manager is working fine or not?

Comment: If you are getting errors then I would start reading into the ULS logs and try to troubleshoot it - here's a good article that might help you get started: http://lennytech.wordpress.com/2013/06/02/troubleshooting-configuration-problems-with-workflow-manager-and-service-bus/

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I know what the problem with my Workflow server is, but thanks for the hint with the uls logs. I will mark Rafals answer as correct.